# echo the total quantity of product even the form is not submitted

Tags: php, jquery, forms

I have a form with `input field` `product`, `quantity` and `total_quantity` is that possible once user input in `quantity field` the the total quantity, echo in `total_quantity field`

**I create a fiddle** [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/myzLuw9n/3/)

for example

`product name   |   quantity`

`product 1      |      2`

`product 2      |      3`

============================

`Total Quantity |      5`

`5` must appear in the total `quantity input field`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('input.more').on('click', function() {
    var $table = $('#input_fields');
    var $tr = $table.find('tr').eq(0).clone();
    $tr.appendTo($table).find('input').val('');
  });

  $("#quick_post").each(function() {
    var form = $(this);

    form.on('keyup', '.orderquan', function() {
      var sum = 0;
      form.find('.orderquan').each(function() {
        sum += +this.value;
      });

      form.find(".total-quan").val(sum);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="quick_post" method="post">
  <table id="input_fields">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input class="orderinput" type="text" name="product[]" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="orderquan" type="text" name="quantity[]" size="1" maxlength="3" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <label>Total Quantity</label>
    <input name="total_Quantity" class="total-quan" value="" />
  </p>
</form>

<input class="more" type="button" value="Addmore" name="addmore" />
```

Comment: thank's for this answer by the way my `<input name="quantity[]" value="" />` is in `array` form is there other way to ride on it because no work in `array` form, sorry if i don't mention it above.

Comment: by the way I have this jquery so i can generate more input field http://jsfiddle.net/gtWu3/

Comment: work like a charm, you save my day's on searching the solution.. thank very much